# Difference between closure and decorator in Python

Tags: python, closures, decorator

This is a program to compute factorial number with cache.

```
def run_closure():
    f = cache(factorial)
    print("5! = %d" % f(5))
    print("5! = %d" % f(5))
    print("4! = %d" % f(4))
    pass


def run_decorator():
    print("5! = %d" % factorial(5))
    print("5! = %d" % factorial(5))
    print("4! = %d" % factorial(4))
    pass


def cache(func):
    table = {}
    def wrapper(n):
        if n in table:
            print("%d is in memo." % n)
            return table[n]
        else:
            print("f(%d) is called." % n)
            table[n] = func(n)
            return table[n]
    return wrapper


# @cache # comment for "run_closure()"; uncomment for "run_decorator" 
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)


def main():
    run_closure()
    # run_decorator()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pass
```

I implement this by means of closure and decorator. The former output:

> f(5) is called.
> 5! = 120
> 5 is in memo.
> 5! = 120
> f(4) is called.
> 4! = 24

The latter output:

> f(5) is called.
> f(4) is called.
> f(3) is called.
> f(2) is called.
> f(1) is called.
> f(0) is called.
> 5! = 120
> 5 is in memo.
> 5! = 120
> 4 is in memo.
> 4! = 24

In the former case, when `5!` is computed, the previous `n!(n<5)` should have been computed and saved into `table` but it didn't. The latter case is what I want. So what's the difference between closure and decorator? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the global variable `table`. Every time cache function is invoked - table variable will be empty at the start. Or you can use cache or lru_cache functions from functools

Comment: Thank you for the reponse! I tried yet the output remained the same. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Using decorator, you change the function itself, and its new version is called recursively. When using closure on the way you do it behaves different: you create function f, which internally keeps calling `factorial`. If you set `factorial=cache(factorial)`, it will behave exactly the same as decorated does.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yet I got an error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'factorial' referenced before assignment". Did I miss something?

Comment: You should either declare it as global (in run_closure first line will be 'global factorial', second 'factorial=cache(factorial)') or perform this assignment not in function (right after factorial definition, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Decorators, in the general sense, are functions or classes that wrap around another object, that extend or decorate the object. The decorator supports the same interface as the wrapped function or object, so the receiver doesn't even know the object has been decorated.

A closure is an anonymous function that refers to its parameters or other variables outside its scope.

So basically, decorators use closures, and not replace them.